Solving a recurrence relation to show that the probability of double-spending decreases exponentially
The paper Analysis of Hashrate-Based Double Spending shows that the probability of a successful double-spending attack in blockchains based on proof of work decreases exponentially with the number of honest confirmations. The paper models the situation as follows.
Let

$H$ be the total network hashrate where $pH$ belongs to the honest miners, $qH$ belongs to the attacker, and $p + q = 1$;
$n$ the number of blocks in the honest chain, $m$ the number of blocks in the attacker's chain, $z = n - m$; and let
$a_z$ be the probability that the attacker's chain will ever become longer than the honest chain when the current difference is $z$. Note that for any $z < 0$, we have $a_z = 1$.

A double-spending attack succeeds when $z < 0$. If it never happens, the attack fails. Because we are interested in whether $z$ will ever become negative, and not when this will happen, this process is equivalent to a discrete-time Markov chain, where each step is defined as finding a block by anyone. The process can be summarized as
$$
z_{i+1} = \begin{cases}
    z_i + 1 & \text{with probability } p \\ 
    z_i - 1 & \text{with probability } q.
\end{cases}
$$
The paper then continues to find $a_z$ for $z \geq 0$ as follows. If the next block found will be by the honest miners, which happens with probability $p$, the attacker will now be $z + 1$ blocks behind and their probability of success will be $a_{z + 1}$ . If the next block found will be by the attacker, which happens with probability $q$, their probability of success will be $a_{z − 1}$ . It follows that $a_z$ satisfies the recurrence relation
$$
a_z = p a_{z + 1} + q a_{z - 1}\ .
$$
The paper then says that by using the fact that $p + q = 1$ and the boundary conditions, it is easy to solve the relation and obtain
$$
a_z = \min (q/p,1)^{\max(z+1, 0)} \ \ \ \  = \begin{cases}
    1                          & \text{if } z < 0    \text{ or }  q >    p \\ 
    \left( q/p \right)^{z + 1} & \text{if } z \geq 0 \text{ and } q \leq p.
\end{cases}
$$
How did they solve it? Or in a more general sense, how can one solve such relations?

The recurrence relation is essentially that of the gambler's ruin with unfair coin flipping (though with the adjustment that you are ruined at $-1$ rather than at $0$) originally solved by Christiaan Huygens over 300 years ago.
